# Wins nss host name resolution not working

Tags: samba, nsswitch

I'm trying to get wins name resolution working. I thought I understood the required step, but I can't get it to work.

The box is running SLES 12 SP1.

This is what I've done:

- Added a wins server to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

  ```
  [global]
      wins server = 10.3.4.60
  ```
- Enabled and started `winbind.service`:

  ```
  # systemctl status winbind.service 
  winbind.service - Samba Winbind Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/winbind.service; enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-05-31 13:25:35 SAST; 1h 27min ago
   Main PID: 32111 (winbindd)
     Status: "winbindd: ready to serve connections..."
     CGroup: /system.slice/winbind.service
             ├─32111 /usr/sbin/winbindd -D
             └─32112 /usr/sbin/winbindd -D

  May 31 13:25:35 vt53ipam01 systemd[1]: Starting Samba Winbind Daemon...
  May 31 13:25:35 vt53ipam01 systemd[1]: winbind.service: Supervising process 32111 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
  May 31 13:25:35 vt53ipam01 winbindd[32111]: [2016/05/31 13:25:35.636807,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_cache.c:3235(initialize_winbindd_cache)
  May 31 13:25:35 vt53ipam01 winbindd[32111]: initialize_winbindd_cache: clearing cache and re-creating with version number 2
  May 31 13:25:35 vt53ipam01 winbindd[32111]: [2016/05/31 13:25:35.637881,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  May 31 13:25:35 vt53ipam01 winbindd[32111]: STATUS=daemon 'winbindd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
  May 31 13:25:35 vt53ipam01 systemd[1]: Started Samba Winbind Daemon.
  ```
- Added the `wins` service to the nsswitch `hosts` database:

  ```
  # grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf 
  hosts:      files dns wins
  ```

If I call `getent` and specify the `wins` service, it works:

```
# getent -s wins hosts VT53TESTSQL01
10.6.27.20      VT53TESTSQL01
```

But calling `getent` with the default service set does not work:

```
# getent hosts VT53TESTSQL01
<nothing returned>
```

I have no idea what I've missed. Any tips on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried rebooting?

from [man nsswitch.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html):

> Within each process that uses nsswitch.conf, the entire file is read
>   only once.  If the file is later changed, the process will continue
>   using the old configuration.